# how to find value is present in binary tree or not

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

please anyone tell me how to find value is present or not  in binary tree ?
i want to find value is present in left or right node of binary tree?

```js
BinarySearchTree.prototype = {

  //more code

  contains: function(value){
    var found       = false,
        current     = this._root

    //make sure there's a node to search
    while(!found && current){

      //if the value is less than the current node's, go left
      if (value < current.value){
        current = current.left;

        //if the value is greater than the current node's, go right
      } else if (value > current.value){
        current = current.right;

        //values are equal, found it!
      } else {
        found = true;
      }
    }

    //only proceed if the node was found
    return found;
  }
}
```

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: `i want to find value is present in left or right node of binary tree` do you mean in the first level? (because there are many "right" and "left" in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping with `while` I suggest using a recursive approach.

```
function searchBST(rootNode, val) {
    if (rootNode.key === null)
        return null;

    var nodeKey = parseInt(rootNode.val);
    if (val < nodeKey) {
        return searchBST(rootNode.left, val);
    } else if (val > nodeKey) {
        return searchBST(rootNode.right, val);
    } else {
        return rootNode.value;
    }
}
```

This function will return the node with the searched value, if you want to only check the presence or not of a node with a certain value, just edit the return values with `false` and `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave the function if the value is found in the tree.

```js
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    // this.left = null;
    // this.right = null;
}

function BinarySearchTree() {
    this._root = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype = {

    insert: function (value) {
        var node = this,
            side = '_root';

        while (node[side]) {
            node = node[side];
            if (value === node.value) {
                return;
            }
            side = value < node.value ? 'left' : 'right';
        }
        node[side] = new Node(value);
    },

    contains: function (value) {
        var current = this._root
        while (current) {
            document.write('value: ' + current.value + '<br>');
            if (value === current.value) {
                return true; // leave the function
            }
            current = value < current.value ? current.left : current.right;
        }
        return false;
    },
};

var tree = new BinarySearchTree(),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tree.insert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
document.write(tree.contains(42) + '<br>');
tree.insert(42);
document.write(tree.contains(42) + '<br>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```