# Binary search tree in JavaScript how to implement the code?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to understand the binary search in java-script so I have found this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Javascript_Data_Structure/0420__Javascript_Binary_Tree.htm).

I have copy pasted that code but can anybody explain how it's working and also tell me how to call main function? I mean what data should I pass so it shows the desired result that are written at last line of code.

```
function Node(data, left, right) {
    this.data = data; // w  w w .ja v  a  2  s. c om
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.show = show;
}
```

How should I call the above method and others?

Comment: Use "new Node();" to make a node. Use something like "new Node("blahblahblah", new Node(true, new Node(/*etc.*/), new Node(/*etc.*/)), new Node(/*etc.*/));" to make a node tree.

Comment: Or use nested arrays to more easily visualize it and then generate the node tree from the array; this would be a better approach, actually.

Comment: Just having nested arrays without a Node object also works.

Comment: You already have the answer in the link that you posted. Please check for `var nums = new BST();` in the page. Thanks.

Comment: you need some code do administrate the tree, like inserting or deleting a node or retrieving all nodes or just the smallest or biggest value or what ever. in this case, the `Node` function does not work alone. you may have a look into this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37300140/1447675) of me for a random filled tree with some methods like `contains` or `insert`. in the snippet output, you can see the tree object with the nodes.